# Fast object sharing between java applications

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, javaspaces

I'm looking for a way to share large in-memory objects between java applications and have been looking at `JMS (ActiveMQ`) and `JavaSpaces`. Will any of theese allow me to reliably send/share objects between two or more java applications? Is ActiveMQ suitable for large messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in-memory data grids like *Oracle Coherence* or *JBoss Data Grid*. This may be a faster then JMS using.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you mean by share. If you mean that different processes (potentially on different machines) need to be able to access a "shared" object, then yes, as the other answer suggests, something like Oracle Coherence would be great.

On the other hand, if you mean share as in to pass from one process to another, then you probably are looking for a messaging solution, e.g. JMS or even simpler e.g. REST.